# Read values from text file and assign them to global variables (constants) in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have a "config" file which is just a .txt file laid out like so:

> VARIABLE_NAME 1
>
> VARIABLE_NAME 2

I'm trying to find a way to read these values in and assign the values to the right of VARIABLE_NAME to the global variables which will be constants (VARIABLE_NAME) in my program. I created a function which reads the file's contents and writes it to a different file, but I'm confused on how to go about reading the contents in the file and somehow storing them as global variables for my program. Any direction/resources on this is greatly appreciated!
Here's the body of my function readAndWriteFileContents()

```
FILE *ptr_file;
FILE *ptr_logFile;
// allocate memory for the info stored in the config file
char *configFileContent = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

// open the files to use
ptr_file = fopen("config.txt", "r");
ptr_logFile = fopen("log.txt", "w");

// if file was not opened successfully, print an error then exit
if (!ptr_file) {
    printf("ERROR: No file found.");
    exit(1);
}

// read the file, printing each line – and write that input file's contents to a log file
while (fgets(configFileContent, sizeof configFileContent, ptr_file) != NULL) {
    // print file contents read
    printf("%s", configFileContent);
    // writes config file's contents to ptr_logFile
    fprintf(ptr_logFile, "%s", configFileContent);
}

// free the memory used to read the config file
free(configFileContent);
// close the files
fclose(ptr_file);
fclose(ptr_logFile);
```

Comment: You could have an array of `struct`s. Each `struct` would store the variable name and its value, perhaps both as strings, or string pointers. Is this a run-time job, or are you trying to generate C source code from the file data?

Comment: @WeatherVane, trying to generate C course code from the file data but wasn't sure if that was even possible. Thanks for the struct suggestion!

Comment: @user3121023 doesn't fgets accept a char *str? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Of course it is possible to generate C source code. The `struct` suggestion was for a runtime scenario. Once you have extracted the data from the input file (with `strtok`?) you can do something like `fprintf(cfile, "int %s = %s;\n", token1, token2);` assuming an `int` is required, or something similar.

Comment: "assign them to ... (constants)" is most unclear.   _Constants_  can not be assigned at run time.